# Is there any way to guarantee that an ElasticSearch index has been deleted

Tags: java, elasticsearch, automated-tests, race-condition

In some automated tests, I am trying to delete and immediately recreate an index at the start of every test, using ElasticSearch's high-level rest client (version 6.4), as follows:

```
DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest = new DeleteIndexRequest(indexName);
deleteIndexRequest.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen());
client.indices().delete(deleteIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
request.mapping("_doc", "{...}", XContentType.JSON);
client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The problem I have is that, intermittently, my tests fail at the point of creating the index, with an error:

```
{"error": {"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [(index-name)/(UUID)] already exists, ...,}] "status":400}
```

The more tests I run, the more likely I am to see the error, which seems to be a strong indicator that it's a race condition - presumably when I try to recreate the index, the previous delete operation hasn't always completed.

This is backed-up with the fact that if I put a breakpoint immediately after the delete operation, and manually run a `curl` request to look at the index that I tried to delete, I find that it's still there some of the time; on those occasions the error above appears if I continue the test.

I've tried asserting the `isAcknowledged()` method of the response to the delete operation, but that always returns `true`, even in cases when the error occurs.

I've also tried doing an `exists()` check before the create operation. Interestingly in that case if I run the tests without breakpoints, the `exists()` check always returns `false` (i.e. that the index doesn't exist) even in cases where the error will then occur, *but* if I put a breakpoint in before the create operation, then the `exists()` check returns `true` in cases where the error will happen.

I'm at a bit of a loss. As far as I understand, my requests should be synchronous, and from a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228048/elasticsearch-delete-index-and-re-create-index), this should mean that the `delete()` operation only returns when the index has definitely been deleted.

I suspect a key part of the problem might be that these tests are running on a cluster of 3 nodes. In setting up the client, I'm only addressing one of the nodes:

```
client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("example.com", 9200, "https")));
```

but I can see that each operation is being replicated to the other two nodes.

When I stop a breakpoint before the create operation, in cases where the index is not deleted, I can see that it's not being deleted on any of the nodes, and it seems not to matter how long I wait, it never gets deleted.

Is there some way I can reliably determine whether the index has been deleted before I create it? Or perhaps something I need to do *before* I attempt the delete operation, to guarantee that it will succeed?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think there are quite a few things to think about. For one I'd test everything with curl or some kind of rest client till I start doing anything in code. Might just help you conceptually, but that's just my opinion.

This is one thing you should consider:
"If an external versioning variant is used, the delete operation automatically creates an index if it has not been created before (check out the create index API for manually creating an index)."
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html
Which kind of would explain why exists() would return false. So if external versioning variant is used then the delete option would actually create an index with the same name prior to deleting it.

You mentioned about the fact that you are working with a three node cluster. Something you can try is:
"When making delete requests, you can set the wait_for_active_shards parameter to require a minimum number of shard copies to be active before starting to process the delete request." Here is a super detailed explanation which is certainly worth reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-wait-for-active-shards

I suggest you try:

```
curl -X DELETE 127.0.0.1:9200/fooindex?wait_for_active_shards=3
```

You said you have 3 nodes in your cluster,so this means that:"...indexing operation will require 3 active shard copies before proceeding, a requirement which should be met because there are 3 active nodes in the cluster, each one holding a copy of the shard."
This check is probably not 100% water tight since according to the docs here:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-wait-for-active-shards
"It is important to note that this setting greatly reduces the chances of the write operation not writing to the requisite number of shard copies, but it does not completely eliminate the possibility, because this check occurs before the write operation commences. Once the write operation is underway, it is still possible for replication to fail on any number of shard copies but still succeed on the primary. The _shards section of the write operation’s response reveals the number of shard copies on which replication succeeded/failed." so perhaps use this parameter, but have your code check the response to see if any operations failed.

Something you can also try is:
(I can't seem to find good documentation to back this info up)
This should be able to tell you if the cluster isn't ready to accept deletes.

```
curl -X DELETE 127.0.0.1:9200/index?wait_for_completion=true
```

Comment: On the point about external versioning, I don't know much about that, but the `exists()` check I mentioned was something I put in immediately before the create operation (after the delete operation), so I don't think it will make a big difference if it's created before the test runs or as part of the delete operation. FWIW, in these cases I'm confident that the index exists before the delete, so I don't think this is relevant (to my specific case).

Comment: I'm not using any aliases, so I don't think that's an issue, but a good thought nonetheless - thank you!

Comment: Finally, I like your suggestion about the `wait_for_active_shards` parameter - you say "see here for further details", but there's no link - are you able to edit your answer to include that?

Comment: Sure will update my answer for the wait_for_active_shards option. Wrote an article about this long ago that I wanted to link to but can't find it. Excellent question btw. I think its cool that you are trying to test for race conditions. Some interesting race conditions exist with nosql based applications, especially from a security point of view.